# Client side Browser Version ASP.NET withouth Compatibility View Enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, internet-explorer

I am little bit confused trying to Retrieve Browser Version from the client side. I use two methods to check this and compare results for test purpose.

1. `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];`
2. `System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;
    string version = browser.Version;`

When I use built in VS2012 Development Server on local dev machine and than view in IE 10 web browser the Results are (what is true for client result):

1. Your Browser Is: IE 10.0
2. Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)

When I upload to production server (IIS 7.5  Windows 2008 R2) and open in the same client web browser (IE 10) or using different client with IE 9, 8 browser the results are as below (what is not true each client have different browser):

1. 7.0
2. Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E)

How I should use above code in C# to have client side browser version not server if my assumption is right.

Comment: BTW, have you tried checking if Compatibility View is active when you browse the production server? (similar to Wyatt's answer, but potentially different solution, namely, disable Compatibility View).

Comment: @TimMedora - You are right. It looks like IE 8,9,10 have Compatibility View for intranet enabled by default this forces the user agent to display IE 7.0 for each one. I disabled checkbox and worked like a charm. Settings for internet sites by default are disabled so there is no problem there. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE will default to legacy mode for some local intranet addresses -- which might well dress it up to look like IE7 to the server.

Add a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to your page and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you. This didn't work yet. I would need to do more research on tip you provided since I am using HTM5 doctype. Not sure why this is not showing correctly I had before HTML 4.01 doctype whit the same results and according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx I shouldn't use IE=edge in production server

Comment: Make sure IE is seeing the doctype you think you are passing -- it is real finnicky. As for not using this on production I think it really depends on how you are building your client-side, I'd rather force everything to modern standards mode than to deal with legacy versions of IE. In fact, we have basically quit dealing with legacy versions of IE for anything fancy now as it ain't worth it. So IE-EDGE is for me. YMMV.

Comment: Yours tip and this [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) helped me how to solve the issue.I used Nuget to add App_Browser package which maintain all newest browser signatures in asp.net 4.0 no need to enable, disable compatibility modes back and fort.